# "(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)"

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the user to submit a form on the homepage and then save that form to a SQL database. However, when the user submits the form, I get the following error: `(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`

This is my `__int__.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from flaskblog1 import routes
```

Comment: I don't use Flask, but FWIW, shouldn't `__int__.py` be `__init__.py`? And is that really the whole error? Shouldn't there be more details? It's important to provide the [full error message](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) (with the traceback if there is one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem I didnt create my data base `db.create_all()`

Comment: I cannot understand your answer .Can You explain further more about this answer

Comment: Even though I created my database like the way you did, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was the database path that had to be changed.

Replace:

> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'

by:

> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'